# How to replace '.' with empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace dot (.) in a string with empty string like this:

1.234 => 1234
However following regex makes it totally empty.

```js
let  x = "1.234";
let y = x.replace(/./g , "");
console.log(y);
```

[image]

However it works good when I  replace comma (,) like this:

```
 let p=x.replace(/,/g , "");
```

What's wrong here in first case i.e. replacing dot(.) by empty string? How it can be fixed?

I am using this in angular.

Comment: You need to escape special characters in regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let x: string = "1.234";
let y = x.replace(/\./g , "");
```

Dot `.` is a special character in Regex. If you need to replace the dot itself, you need to **escape** it by adding a backslash before it: `\.`

Read more about Regex special characters here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: You probably should add that . is the wildcard character that matches one of anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/[.]/g` instead of simply `/./g` as `.` matches almost `any character` except `whitespaces`

```js
console.log('3.14'.replace(/[.]/g, '')); // logs 314
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do this(another post have already answered it with regex) is to use `split` which will create an array and then use `join` to join the elements of the array

```js
let x = "1.234";
// splitting by dot(.) delimiter
// this will create an array of ["1","234"]
let y = x.split('.').join('');  // join will join the elements of the array
console.log(y)
```